# In Ionic (Angular), I can’t access a predefined global variable from a template’s .controller() after refresh. Why?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, refresh, rootscope

In Ionic, I have predefined a global variable in the .run() of app.js, like $rootScope.obj1 = {}, which can be accessed in a template’s .controller() when the web application was first time loaded.

But after that page was refreshed in the browser by user, the same accessing in the .controller() got an “undefined” result.

I ever wondered if the .run() function wasn’t invoked during the refresh. But after some tests I found that it WAS invoked. When I refresh the page, the sequence of invokes seems to be: the .controller() of the page, then the .config() in the app.js, and then the .run() in the app.js, not like the first time loading, during which the .run() was invoked before the .controller(). That’s why I can’t access the $rootScope.obj1 in the .controller() again.

Is what I thought true? And if so, how can I solve this problem? Where the predefined global variables should be put in the best practice?

Comment: I doubt the order would be different after refresh. Could be a race-condition (try several refreshes) but I would need your sample code to see.

Comment: Thanks for your so prompt reply!

app.js
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.runningMode = 0;
});

controllers.js
.controller("OrdersCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    alert($rootScope.runningMode);
});

First time, I got a "0". And after refresh, I got an "undefined".

Comment: Thanks for your so prompt reply!

`code`
app.js
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.runningMode = 0;
});

controllers.js
.controller("OrdersCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    alert($rootScope.runningMode);
});
`code`

First time, I got a "0". And after refresh, I got an "undefined".

Comment: Please edit your question, cannot read code in comments XD

Comment: app.js
    .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.runningMode = 0;
    });

controllers.js
    .controller("OrdersCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        alert($rootScope.runningMode);
    });

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make out the markdown effect.